# How to call an Observer method from a different file?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and have been trying to program a file that calls from another file. Lets say I have file A.java and it has an observer method

...

```
//in Item.java

public class Item{
    private String name;
     
    //parametrized cons
    public Item(String name){
        this.name = name;    
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And lets say in file B.java I want to print all Item.names, I thought it would be something like this

```
//in Bag.java
public class Bag {
    private int size;

    public void print(){
        // this does not work 
        System.out.println(Item.getName());
    }
}
```

But this didn't work. I can't change the method (name) of print at all. Is there another way this can be done?

Goal: Sorry If I am not being clear, the goal is to print the name of an item. Assuming we passed an item to the Item.java class already, how would you print that item?

Comment: Please show the full contents of both files. As written, an "Observer" isn't shown

Comment: @OneCricketeer Updated

Comment: @Progman Sorry, still figuring out definitions of the language as well. I updated it again, The goal is to print the item that was passed into the Item.java from Bag.java

Comment: You need a Bag to hold onto _some_ Item. How do you plan on doing that? In other words, `.getName()` is an instance method. You need an instance of `new Item()`. Where in your code are you doing **that**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear how B would know about A in your given code, but you can pass it in when you create a `new B()` via the constructor

```
public class B {
  private A a;

  public B(A a) {
     this.a = a;
  }  

  public void print() {
    System.out.println(this.a.getName());
  }
}
```

Or you can define a static method in B that accepts an A instance

```
public static void print(A a) {
   System.out.println(a.getName());
}
```

And call `B.print(a_instance)`

Answer (score 0):

```
//in B.java
public void print(){
    System.out.println(new A().getName());
}
```

Comment: So in my A file I have a parameterized constructor A(input, input, input) when I do the new A().getName() it asks me to re enter the 3 inputs

Comment: so you can pass them like this `new A("some string value", 12, true)`, just make sure you are passing the value according to the datatype, thank you.